# How may I Check Certain Screen Colors in Pygame with a Certain Tolerance?

Tags: python, pygame

Good evening! I am using Pygame's Surface.get_at() function below the character coordinates to check if the player is on a surface that is walk-able. I chose the color black (0, 0, 0) as walking surface, but Pygame sometimes returns (1, 0, 0) as the color, and thus, the player cannot stand on that surface. Is there some way to use a range of numbers as an int so that any color near black can be used as walking surface? Is there an easier way to do this? Here is the part of my program that I am working on:

```
groundcolor = disp.get_at((int(playerx), int(playery)-1))
    if groundcolor == black1 or groundcolor == black0:
        groundlim = int(playery)
        print(groundcolor)

    if groundcolor != black1 and groundcolor != black0:
        groundlim = 695
        if playery != 695:
            jumping = True
            print(groundcolor)
```

Note: black1 is (1,0,0) and black0 is (0,0,0). I did this just to attempt to fix my problem, but there are too many near-black colors to define them all.

Any other recommendations apart from my addressing question would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

You could check if the colour values are below a certain point like

```
if groundcolor[0] < 5 and groundcolor[1] < 5 and groundcolor[2] < 5:
    #walkable
```

You could also use [Masks](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html#pygame.mask.from_threshold). With masks you can get pixel perfect collisions with any shape. And you can create masks of the screen from the colour, which is what you want.

example of using masks.

```
#create the screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))

#draw background object white
pygame.draw.rect(screen,(255,255,255),(100,100,200,50))
pygame.draw.rect(screen,(255,255,255),(400,40,60,200))
pygame.draw.rect(screen,(255,255,255),(200,300,200,50))

#create mask using white as the collision areas, (1,1,1) is the threshold
#so (1,1,1) is an exact match so mabye change to (0.9, 0.9, 0.9)
screen_mask = pygame.mask.from_threshold(screen,(255,255,255),(1,1,1))

#do the same for the player
class player:
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_threshold(self.image,(0,255,0),(1,1,1))
        ...
        #if your player is an image, not one colour, then you can do 
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.image)
        #which goes off transparency
```

then to check for collisions

```
if screen_mask.overlap(player.mask,(player.rect.x,player.rect.y))
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. I implemented this idea, but another question arises. How may I use Pygame's get_at for more area? Some of the black surfaces are too small for the one pixel get_at for the player to stand on.

Comment: @NicholasPlasmodiumViCannonPl `get_at` becomes really inefficient when you start to areas, it even says that in the [docs](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_at). I would recommend using masks, I will update answer to show example of using masks

Comment: Thank you so much for all this work! I am very glad to have this code to study so that I may better my program. I appreciate it

Comment: No problem, If you cant get it working, just leave a comment and update the question if you need and ill have a look

Comment: Actually, may I ask one more thing? The way I have the background is an image (PNG) that I fit to the screen using pygame. Is there a way to create the masks for any color that is black or near-black? I made the background in MS Paint, and the black lines are what I wish to be the platforms (this also makes it so much easier to adjust the platforms as I can just draw more black lines.) Therefore, could I mask every near-black pixel on screen?

Comment: Yes. Once you load in the png image with `pygame.image.load`, it will return a surface, which you can then use to create the mask, Just like the above example, you can use `pygame.mask.from_threshold(image, (0,0,0), (0.9, 0.9, 0.9))` This will create a mask the size of the image, with the collision area any pixel that is 90%+ black, Then if you want to create more platforms, you could rather update your picture or draw in pygame

Comment: Should the "image" be the display, the imported image, or something else?

Comment: it shouldn't matter too much, at most you may need to add a few lines of code. But the imported image would probably be the easiest. Then you can don't have to worry about other objects on the screen getting in the way. As the image will be the same the whole time. And you still easily change the image to create/destroy platforms

Comment: Is it possible to check for screen mask overlapping with player x and y coords?

Comment: Do you mean overlap with player mask or pixels?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212223/discussion-between-plasmodiumfalciparum-and-the-big-kahuna).

Answer (score 1):

You can use numpy.linalg.norm to calculate the euclidean distance of a vector from the origin (0,0,0) and set a threshold. So for example, the following:

```py
import numpy as np

a = (1,0,0)
b = (1,1,0)
c = (2,0,0)
d = (1,2,3)

print(np.linalg.norm(a))
print(np.linalg.norm(b))
print(np.linalg.norm(c))
print(np.linalg.norm(d))
```

will output

```
1.0
1.4142135623730951
2
3.7416573867739413
```

So you can define a number as the threshold and modify the conditionals in your code like this:

```py
if np.linalg.norm(groundcolor) < threshold:
```

and

```py
if np.linalg.norm(groundcolor) >= threshold:
```

If you want to calculate the distance from a color that isn't (0,0,0) simply subtract that color from the ground color. For example:

```py
if np.linalg.norm(groundcolor-green) < threshold:
```

Note that it doesn't matter if the result of the subtraction contains negative values, norm functions by definition always produce real numbers greater than or equal to zero:

```py
print(np.linalg.norm((-1,0,0)))
```

will output:

```
1.0
```